# Running lm() errror: Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r, linear-regression, glm

I keep getting this error and I don't understand what I am supposed to change

Here is the code I am using.

```
fit <- elsa12 %>%
   lm(formula = notact1~cesd2, data = elsa12)%>%
    filter(!is.na(notact1),!is.na(ncesd2))
```

> Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'.

Comment: the second expression is a model output with `lm` and it stores output in a `list`, `filter` is used (if from `dplyr`) is used on a data.frame/tibble

Comment: so what should i do to fix it?

Comment: Please consider to edit your post with a small reproducible example with `dput` and your expected output. Your post shows only code and error which is not that helpful for others to test and to help you

Answer (score 1):

I think

```r
fit <- (elsa12 
     %>% lm(formula = notact1~cesd2)
)
```

should work.

- you don't need to specify `data=elsa12` in the `lm()` call (the pipe automatically feeds `elsa12` to `lm()` as the first unspecified argument, which in this case is `data`), and in fact this confuses R because it thinks you're specifying the *next* argument, which is `subset` — that is the *proximal* cause of your error ("invalid subscript type 'list'")
- your `filter` should be unnecessary because `lm()` automatically drops cases that have `NA` in any of the model variables
- even if you did want to use `filter`, it looks like it was in the wrong order (i.e. you should have used `elsa12 %>% filter(...) %>% lm(...)`)